# RegEx to extract array of strings in javascript using match()

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to use `string.match()` in javascript with a regular expression to extract an array of strings.

Here is a sample string:

```
CREATE TABLE "listings" (
        "listing_id"    INTEGER UNIQUE,
        "state" TEXT,
        "title" TEXT,
        "description"   TEXT,
        "price" TEXT,
        "currency_code" TEXT,
        "url"   TEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY("listing_id")
```

Expected results:

```
['listing_id', 'state', 'title', 'description', 'price', 'currency_code', 'url']
```

what I've tried:
`/(?<!\()(\").+?(\")(?!\ \()/g`

Comment: Regex is not good for formatting, but you can the strings with this: /(?<=\(.{2,})(?<=\")\w+(?=")/gs

Comment: @PoulBak You are missing a parenthesis in your regex. Your regex also gets the "listings" in the first line, and "listing_id" in the last line, which I don't want.

Comment: Please find another solution, namely a proper SQL parser.

Comment: Formatting ate the escape character: /(?<=\\(.{2,})(?<=\")\w+(?=")/gs Now it should work, however the 's' flag is not supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
/(?<=CREATE TABLE[^(]*\([^()]*)"([^"]*)"/g
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Th4aU1/1). The expression will match strings between double quotes preceded with `CREATE TABLE (` and any strings other than parentheses.

JavaScript:

```js
const regex = /(?<=CREATE TABLE[^(]*\([^()]*)"([^"]*)"/g;
const str = `CREATE TABLE "listings" (
        "listing_id"    INTEGER UNIQUE,
        "state" TEXT,
        "title" TEXT,
        "description"   TEXT,
        "price" TEXT,
        "currency_code" TEXT,
        "url"   TEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY("listing_id")`;
const matches = str.matchAll(regex)
console.log(Array.from(matches, x => x[1]));
```

Comment: Thx, but it also gets the quotation marks around the strings, which I don't want.

Comment: @user1819087 Did you click "Run code snippet"? The result has no quotation marks. Capturing group is used to get the values without them.

Comment: @user1819087 You can't do it without consuming quotes, the left and right delimiters are identical. You cannot use lookarouns only.

Comment: Thx, I didn't know about `matchAll`. It is working now.

Comment: @RyszardCzech you can also do it with lookarounds alone, see my answer

Comment: @Sundeep Yours is not generic, once the query gets a bit messed up, there [will be no match](https://regex101.com/r/QoQXxj/1), while mine will [still find](https://regex101.com/r/Th4aU1/2) the correct matches.

Comment: @RyszardCzech I'm working with what's mentioned in the question... https://regex101.com/r/QoQXxj/2 for your modified example, again it will work without needing matchAll

Answer (score 1):

Adding Parentheses around the actual string content solves it: `(?<!\()(\")(.+?)(\")(?!\ \()`, matching group 2.

Live example: http://regexr.com/58m4i

Comment: Thx, but it also gets the quotation marks around the strings, which I don't want.

Comment: For me, this does not get the quotation marks, when only selecting matching group `2`.

Comment: Thx. With your solution I was getting just the quotes when using `matchAll`. I had to use this instead: `/(?<!\()\"(.+?)\"(?!\ \()/g`

Answer (score 0):

Solution without having to use `matchAll`

If you need to match `CREATE TABLE` and then get the content between double quotes at the start of line:

```
ip_str.match(/(?<=CREATE TABLE.*^\s*")[^"]+(?=")/gms)
```

If `CREATE TABLE` doesn't need to be matched:

```
ip_str.match(/(?<=^\s*")[^"]+(?=")/gm)
```

The main trick here is to use `m` flag to anchor the search to start of line.